# How to find intersection of sublists of sublists in Python3.0?

Tags: python, list, intersection

Imagine a list like:

```
SuperList = [[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]],[[6,3,1],[9,0,4]]]
```

As you can see I have a sublist inside a sublist.
How can I code it find the intersection of those sublists.?
In this case the answer is 1,3 and 4.
My goal is to append all elements that appear at least once in each sublist in a new list(it doesn't matter if it appears in all sublists of one sublist)

I tried with set.intersection, but constantly I get

```
'unhashable type: 'list''
```

or while trying to unwind the list I get

```
'can't use the starred expression here'!
```

Comment: Are you trying to find out does `1` occurs anywhere, or trying to find the exact sublist in which occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the sublists and take their intersection using [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
>>> set.intersection(*[{x for lst in sub for x in lst} for sub in SuperList])
set([1, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Moses are you Moses? Thanks man! I really appreciate! I had been working ON this 10 15 hours and in the end it was so simple! Novice programmer struggles i guess! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what exactly you are trying to do, but if you are trying to **test for existence** of an element (for example `1`) in **any of the sublists**, you can first flatten the "super list", and than make a set from that list.

We can do it in one go with `flatset()`:

```
def flatset(lst):
    try:
        return set(lst)
    except TypeError:
        s = set()
        for item in lst:
            s.update(flatset(item))
        return s
```

For example:

```
>>> superlist = [[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]],[[6,3,1],[9,0,4]]]
>>> flatset(superlist)
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9])
>>> 1 in flatset(superlist)
True
```